How is it possibile a SQLIntegrityConstraintViolationException with INSERT ... ON DUPLICATE KEY?
I'm facing a very strange and nonsense error in MariaDB 10.11.
I have a simple table with an integer as primary key.
This is the query:
INSERT INTO mytable (id, myfield) VALUES (?,?) ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE myfield=?;

I found this error:
 INSERT INTO mytable (id, myfield) VALUES (?,?) ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE
 myfield=?]; (conn=248) Duplicate entry '18163' for key 'PRIMARY';
 nested exception is java.sql.SQLIntegrityConstraintViolationException:
 (conn=248) Duplicate entry '18163' for key 'PRIMARY'

How it is possibile a duplicate primary key error with ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE statement?

Check triggers.

Good tip, but there aren't triggers in this table.

I cannot reproduce (in mysql alone) https://dbfiddle.uk/DUWKudc5

@Tobia Please [edit] your question to include the full complete CREATE TABLE statement for the mytable table. Also add the parameter values you are using in your prepared statement. And write in your question if you have an existing row in your table with the id 18163.

^ this, but please do a show create table mytable; to get the create table statement, not some other source.

also show output of select version();

Thank you all, finally I solve with a truncate and a table restore. Can it be an index corruption? It doesn't make sense a duplicate key with "ON DUPLICATE" statement

How does your program know "18163"?

Yes it is a valid entry. But the error goes away after a full restore (truncate + inserts) of the table.
